# how to get the input given by a user through collect in a worflow through designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

i am using collect keyword to get an input from the user.
now inside the collect;

i have a custom form field with the name update status.
update status - choice field - user will be able togive approved/ rejected.

now in the sahrepoint designer workflow;
collect "Name" from "Jiben" (Output to variable:collect).

i want to update a field "STATUS" in the list associated with the workflow using the input from the user ?

is there any way to do that.
i am sturggling for doing this from today morning :( please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [explained here](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/collect-data-from-a-user-in-a-workflow-HA010209808.aspx#BM5) you will need to get your "Name" field via looking it up in the related tasks.

Let's say you have a collect data from user activity. "New Task". It has one custom field "MyField" (Text). It gets this data from user X and Output is set to Variable "collect". This variable will be the TaskID you want to look up.

So to set the field "Status" on your current list item, you can use a "Set Field in CUrrent Item" Activity. You only need to click the "Fx" and select the Task list where you have your collect data activity store your tasks (Association: Task List), Field from Source will be "MyField" and the Find the List Item you only need to set the Field to "ID" and the Value to "collect".

You should read [some tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+designer+2010+tutorial) on how to design a workflow with Sharepoint Designer as there are many easy explanations and even nice sample videos explaining exactly your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot moontear for the explanations and links provided. i was able to do the design the workflow in the desinger.